# Reshape JSON array in to single JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, arraylist

I have following JSON array in my code

```
jsonList = [{"catName":"Carrom"}, {"catName":"Rugby"}]
```

In my case I want it to be look like this as a single JSON

```
{ "catName": "Carrom", "catName": "Rugby" }
```

How can I convert the abov JSON array to a single JSON ? What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: The output you're suggesting isn't valid JSON as you've got duplicate property names...

Comment: like comment above, if you'd like to parse your output, you'll get `{catName: "Rugby"}`

Comment: @DavidMcEleney Yes. But I want it in that way since I want to use it like this
`"$match": {
                "category": { "$elemMatch": { "catName": "Rugby", "catName": "Carrom" }},
            }`
So, I want to convert it into this format

Comment: @SuthuraSudharaka That won't work - it seems like you need something like `$in`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Comment: How can two keys have same name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the above comment by @JohannesReuter I changed my `$match` as follows now it works fine.

Thanks everyone for the help

Change in my api

```
        `"$match": {
            "category": { "$elemMatch": { "catName": { "$in": ["Chess", "Rugby"] } } 
         },
        }`
```

Now I'm converting my json to this `["Chess", "Rugby"]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe keep as an array of objects and use `lodash` to filter?

```
var catArray = [{"catName":"Carrom"}, {"catName":"Rugby"}];

_.find(catArray, { 'catName': 'Carrom' });
```

This will return any elements that match that query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work for you

```
// Do this for every json
var attributes = Object.keys(json1)

for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
  jsonresult[attributes[i]] = json1[attributes[i]]
}
```